# How to hide website's Vue.js admin panel code from unauthorized clients

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a website, running on Laravel 8 and Vue.js 3. Admin panel's front-end is completely on Vue, while guest users are served with Laravel's blade.

I have worries about unauthorized client's possibility to inspect admin panel's code on login page, as it's part of Vue.

Of course, client will not get any information from server, without authentication. All she/he can see is blank panel with no information at all.

So the problem is, client can analyze a whole functionality of code, view all routes that is used to manage site content. This gives full information to security researchers where to target, what to send and what to expect.

Also, I know about *Asynchronous Components*, but this is not answer here, as those component's are named by predictable names. So it's possible to get whole working code anyway.

If I will make subdomain separately, those subdomains can be also scanned and exposed. As managers are working from separate locations, denying of route, based on IP address is also not solution.

How to control this from Laravel, so only authenticated users can see panel's code? Should I try to fix this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do is by compiling two differents files using webpack and a logical test whitin the blade file.

So, depending on the user type, the page will load differents files, but I do not mind them staying in the public directory. I put every administrator request inside an administrator middleware.

You can make laravel moving files from public directory and an another one using some sort of control. Exposing your admin files only when an administrator request a page and until the load is done. I know this is possible, I never tested it myself.